# How can a screen display transparent colors?

Tags: colors, screen, rgb, rgba

A screen typically displays 24 bits colors (RGB) so 16M possible colors. So what is the point to have RGBA colors if we cannot display them? And why I can see this 50% transparent red on my RGB monitor?

(I can't post images but imagine a color picker with red selected and the transparency slider set to 50%)

```
---------------------------
|                        o|
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
---------------------------
Transparency : --------o-------
Color : #ff000080  <-- this color asks for 32 bits to be represented but my 24 bit monitor can display it...
```

Comment: See: [Alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing). There is another reason for using 4 bytes per pixel instead of 3 (other then transparency): In modern CPUs/GPUs it is more efficient to access memory and process data in units of 32 bits. See: [A programmer's view on digital images](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2016/02/16/a-programmers-view-on-digital-images-the-essentials/#targetText=A%20pixel%20is%20usually%2032,X%20in%20pixel%20format%20names).

Comment: Screen do no display transparent colours. Your OS/windows manager/app will merge several planes, according the transparency (and filter/merging rules), but the signal sent to screen is just the colour of every pixel. Note: background plane is often special (special rules in case of transparent colours).

Comment: There are [see-through display technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See-through_display) which allow so-called "transparent colors"; however, see-through computer screens in laptops, desktops, and smartphones are not yet ubiquitous among consumers.